# PCA for Sentinel2 SVM and RF classification

Tags: svm, random-forest, pca, google-earth-engine, sentinel2

I am attempting to classify dump pile in google earth engine. Using Sentinel 2 data and classifying the first 5 PCAs lead to the best visual result. Here the [PCA code](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/339247/google-earth-engine-error-when-computing-pca-of-sentinel-2-mosaiced-image) used in [script with Sentinel2](https://code.earthengine.google.com/eea8b4fc6eb6929ed25a31a1f37ac784).

1. Is there a way of iteratively testing SVM parameters in google earth engine and select best fit based on ROC, AUC.
2. How to limit overfittig (other than visual inspection)?